# Symfony - Insert values programatically into CSS files

Tags: php, html, css, symfony

Ok, here's the scenario. We have a Symfony2 project and the same core code is shared by two websites, the 2nd website simply has its own App folder, with the src and vendor folders symlinked to the 'master' install. This works great and with the specific parameters in the 2nd app folder, allows us to run with a different database and thus offer the same technical solution to two companies. hurrah :)

BUT. We obviously want them styled differently via CSS, the values for which need to come out of the database. I realise we could simply code them, but with future projects in mind, we want them to be in the database and thus easy to update centrally.

So, the problem is how can we insert these database sourced values into the CSS file? I've looked into SASS etc, which would be a step in the right direction, but the values are still defined within the CSS file, not outside it.

We could do a dynamic CSS file, powered by Twig, but that's frankly using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Has anyone come across this problem and found a suitable answer?

Comment: I suggest using LessCSS (http://leafo.net/lessphp/), you can define variables containing values for css properties, compiling it and get a css file.

Comment: Ah, that looks promising - thanks. I'll feedback when I've looked into it further.

Answer (score 0):

I did never try it but i think that you can render a css file with Twig like you render any other file. You only have to create a route, a controller and a view.

Sorry did not read last rules..
You could add a datetime stamp in the css mysql-table. Is it changed? Render and save a new version of your css file. Otherwise skip it.

On the other hand Twig uses caching as much as posible so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a service that write a css file in your css folder.
Call this services when you make any changes in the DB. (You can make a listener for that).

You could also use [asseticBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#assets) to manage all your css files.